# attributeerror module 'time' has no attribute 'clock' (pyqt5)

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I understand that `time.clock()` has been deprecated since Python 3.3.
However, the error is occurring when I am trying to import the pyqtgraph module:

```
import pyqtgraph
```

That is the only line in the file, and this is the error:

```
  File "D:\2020Backup\2020Backup\code\Python\PyQt\graphs\first.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyqtgraph
  File "C:\Users\mpnlo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\__init__.py", line 204, in <module>
    from .graphicsItems.VTickGroup import *
  File "C:\Users\mpnlo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\graphicsItems\VTickGroup.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .. import functions as fn
  File "C:\Users\mpnlo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\functions.py", line 17, in <module>
    from . import debug
  File "C:\Users\mpnlo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\debug.py", line 11, in <module>
    from . import ptime
  File "C:\Users\mpnlo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\ptime.py", line 24, in <module>
    cstart = systime.clock()  ### Required to start the clock in windows
AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock'
```

I was wondering if anyone knows a workaround for this issue, perhaps a way for me to update the erroneous in the module, I am using the most recent version of pyqtgraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a workaround, if this is happening to you, would be to use, the matplotlib module integrated into pyqt5, this page outlines how to do this:

https://pythonspot.com/pyqt5-matplotlib/

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Compile the latest pyqtgraph with `pip3 install --upgrade git+http://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph.git`

Comment: Hi, would you be able to link me a tutorial on what git is, and how to make it work in this application? I tried to install git, but there was no option to add to PATH, and I can't find a tutorial to make it appear in PATH

Comment: ERROR: Error [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified while executing command git clone -q http://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph.git 'C:\Users\mpnlo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-i0lsdmyg'
ERROR: Cannot find command 'git' - do you have 'git' installed and in your PATH?

Comment: Though it doesn't matter now, I really appreciate your help but I found a way to integrate matplotlib into pyqt5 and that seems to be working for the minute!

Comment: Git should be added to path by default, you will definitely need to restart your shell to refresh environmental vars. You can search how to do that or just do a restart.